# Why is snowflake schema normalized?

Tags: database, data-warehouse, star-schema

Why is the snowflake schema normalized, even though the data warehouse has the property of being denormalized? I am learning about data warehouse technologies, can anyone elaborate on this for me?
I apologize if I am missing something here, I am open to suggestions. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think data warehouse schemas are denormalized?  That’s not really a constructive way to think about it.

Comment: When you build a database schema, you go through a data modelling exercise, and during that exercise the data modeller may decide that an appropriate design is to implement a snowflake schema instead of a star schema (... or a standard OLTP schema .... or a data vault schema.... or a EAV schema). Data is modelled to fit requirements and constraints. A snowflake schema might fit those. This gentleman has some interesting and amusing reads about data modelling and the mistakes that can be made https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/when-the-fever-is-over-and-ones-work-is-done/

Comment: Thanks, @David Browne - Microsoft for the response. I am going through some literature online and mostly it is written that data warehouses are de-normalized to enhance the query processing.

Comment: Thanks, @Nick.McDermaid for your response. I will surely check the link you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Data warehouses may be denormalised but that’s not mandatory, only some kinds of data warehouse modelling use denormalisation as part of its design principles.

For a dimension, a snowflake model describes when a dimension is modelled using normalisation. It could still be part of a data warehouse though.

The kimball approach advises to avoid snowflakes in a data warehouse because it prefers denormalised dimensions.